# Is the path of an electron between successive collisions (with positive ions of the metal)a straight line in the presence of electric field?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electrons, electric-current

I feel that the answer should be yes. While the entire journey isn't straight, the journey between successive collisions is straight. But the internet and my book says the opposite (the path is curved). Please clarify this.

Comment: The internet does not say anything. Please quote and reference your source.

Comment: Link:https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/what-is-the-nature-of-path-of-free-electrons-in-a-conductor/current-electricity/3599658. Link 2:https://www.zigya.com/study/book?class=12&board=cbse&subject=Physics&book=Physics+Part+I&chapter=Current+Electricity&q_type=&q_topic=Drift+of+Electrons+and+the+Origin+of+Resistivity&q_category=&question_id=PHEN12049586

Comment: @my2cts I have put up links. Look into it,  please.

Comment: The links you've provided, are from websites which aren't trustworthy, IMO.

Comment: @FakeMod Oh, but these websites are one of the most reliable ones in my country, India. But I shall try to make an effort to look into more competent websites next time to clear my doubts. :)

Comment: Well, it might seem so, but places like StackExchange are more reliable, and FWIW, I am also from India :-) So I know these websites.

Comment: Could you update your question, not the comments, with some good links ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't necessary for the entire journey to be straight. The path taken by a charged body under the influence of electric field is a straight line *only if* **the direction of the velocity and the electric field are same at every point on the path** (this also includes *the starting point*). However, in such random collisions under the influence of a random electric field, there's no guarantee that the electron will undergo a straight path. Even if you somehow make the electric field constant and uniform, still the electron will undergo a [*parabolic path*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) (which is curved) almost all the time. In this case, the motion of the electron will be analogous to the motion of a [projectile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

Comment: I did not understand when you said direction of electric field and velocity is same at every point. Are we talking about all the charged particles or one charged particle?

Comment: @leah In my answer, I am only analyzing the motion of a single charged particle/electron.

Comment: What if there was no electric field? Would it be a straight path still?

Comment: Also the direction of electric field is constant at any instant. So the parameter to look at would be the direction of charged particle's velocity?

Comment: @leah In absence of any electric fields (which is impractical), the path would be a straight line (neglecting gravity). Yes, it's the charge's initial velocity which decides the path taken by the charge inthe subsequent motion.

Comment: Thanks! I was completely at sea about this question.

Comment: @leah You can also consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer.